# Keithley 2410 and PyVISA - VI_ERROR_TMO: Timeout expired before operation completed

Tags: python, linux, visa, data-acquisition, pyvisa

I'm trying to control a Keithley 2410 via python on an x86_64 linux machine (CentOS 7). I'm using python 2.7.5, NI-VISA 16 and PyVISA 1.8. The Keithley is connected to the computer via a a RS232-to-USB cable and it's configured for RS232 communication (with the parameters: baud 57600, bits 8, parity none, terminator , flow-ctrl none). When I try to query the Keithley I get a timeout error, as shown below:

```
>>> import visa
>>> rm = visa.ResourceManager()
>>> print(rm.list_resources())
(u'ASRL1::INSTR', u'ASRL2::INSTR')
>>> keithley = rm.open_resource("ASRL2::INSTR")
>>> print(keithley.query('*IDN?'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyvisa/resources/messagebased.py", line 407, in query
return self.read()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyvisa/resources/messagebased.py", line 332, in read
message = self.read_raw().decode(enco)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyvisa/resources/messagebased.py", line 306, in read_raw
chunk, status = self.visalib.read(self.session, size)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyvisa/ctwrapper/functions.py", line 1582, in read
ret = library.viRead(session, buffer, count, byref(return_count))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyvisa/ctwrapper/highlevel.py", line 188, in _return_handler
raise errors.VisaIOError(ret_value)
pyvisa.errors.VisaIOError: VI_ERROR_TMO (-1073807339): Timeout expired before operation completed.
```

Answer (score 2):

PyVISA 1.8 should default to '\r' line termination for serial, so your 2410 may not be receiving the '\n' it needs to start it parsing the command. [Try doing](http://pyvisa.readthedocs.io/en/stable/resources.html#termination-characters)

```
keithley.write_termination = '\n'
keithley.read_termination = '\n'
```

right after your `open_resource()` call.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestion but it seems as though I needed to explicitly set the baud rate.

```
rm = visa.ResourceManager()
smu = rm.open_resource("ASRL2::INSTR")
smu.baud_rate = 57600
```